# Why app.liste err showing undefined, and also localhost is loading forever?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, backend, mern

I started woking with my first ever mern project, and i got stucked here.

At start of the project its loaded perfectly in localhost chrome, but after i added mongodb code,
it started breaking. I mean now server is loaded  forever. I tried by changing various ports, cleared browser cache and browser history. I tried every possible answer that i got from stackover flow and other resources.

But still couldnt sort out problem.

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
require('./dbConfig/config')
const cors = require("cors");
const dotenv = require("dotenv")
const app = express();
const Register = require('./models/UserSchema')

//middleware
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json);
//posting
app.get('/', (req, resp)=> {
  resp.send("working")
})



//connection to server

const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

app.listen( port , (err) => console.log(err, port));



//Terminal 


[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
undefined 8080
mongo working
```

Answer (score 0):

now it will read the port from env file else port will be 8080

```
require("dotenv").config();

const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`);
})
```

Comment: I think the problem with mongodb connection. Because i created a complete new codebase for backend, and it worked well with server.

Comment: Here im attaching mongo connection, if you found any error please rectify it, thanks.                                                   const mongoose = require('mongoose')
mongoose.set("strictQuery", true);
//Mongodb connection
//mongodb://localhost::27017/  wont work properly sometimes so run cmd saying //mongosh and you will get mongoose connection string
//mongodb://localhost:27017
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/ecomm',{
     useNewUrlParser: true,
     useUnifiedTopology: true 
})
.then(() => console.log('mongo working'))
.catch((err) => console.log(err))

Comment: change the connection uri `mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/ecomm` to `mongodb://0.0.0.0:27017/ecomm` and it will work!